# Load a dataset in matlab for knn classification

Tags: matlab, dataset, classification, knn

Hello guys actually i want to load this dataset in matlab for executing knn classification on it but i dont know how to do so .i have tried load and readtable and ... but it didnt work then i have tried this code

```
FID=fopen('file','rt');
a=textscan(FID,''...);
```

But actually i could not find out what is text format to take data that i wanted so it was a dead end does any one can help me with this.please

This is how inside of my data file looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFakF.png)

this is the dataset file http://lms.ui.ac.ir/public/group/a7/b2/06/6a5fb_24fb.gz

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something as the following:

**EDIT: code now imports file correctly**

```
FID = fopen('toy.m','rt');
data = {};
i = 1;
while ~feof(FID)
    line = fgetl(FID);
    line = fgetl(FID);
    if feof(FID)
        break;   
    end
    %sprintf('%d %s', i, line) %debug
    if (isempty(line))
        headers = 3;
    elseif (line(1) ~= '#')
        headers = 2;
    else
        headers = 1;
    end
    rows = textscan(FID, '%s %s %d', 1, 'headerlines', headers);
    data{i} = cell2mat(textscan(FID, '', rows{3}, 'headerlines', 2));
    i = i + 1;
end
fclose(FID);

fprintf('File contained %d blocks of data\n', i);

fprintf('To access a value in cell "data", for example value (1,2) inside the second matrix, digit "data{2}(1,2)": ');
data{2}(1,2)
```

Comment: hi ,thanks for your help but it didnt work and produced an error  : Buffer overflow (bufsize = 4095) while reading string from
file (row 1002, field 1). Use 'bufsize' option.

Comment: i have put the dataset in my question if you want to give it a try

Comment: @MaryGh I have tried to open the file with word processors but it does not look like a numeric database, it looks like text in a non-Latin alphabet

Comment: can you open it in this address please.  https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/705983-load-a-dataset-in-matlab-for-knn-classification

Comment: you can open it in matlab .open gz file and drag and drop file inside ,inside of matlab command window then you can see dataset

Comment: @MaryGh I cannot cut and paste the input inside my answer because I guess non-Latin script is not allowed; opening the file with Matlab results in the same bunch of symbols, no number in there

Comment: Can i send you .m file somwhere??

Comment: Maybe you can cut and paste the whole .m file in your question

Comment: I have put my file in this question in mathworks website

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/705983-load-a-dataset-in-matlab-for-knn-classification

Comment: Yay my friend thanks for your help but im still working on it.